# Jackson with proguard is not sending data properly

Tags: android, json, jackson, proguard

I am working on `com.fasterxml.jackson` library using ObjectMapper and JsonProperty.

I scanned almost all stackoverflow questions but couldn't find the answer.

Json data gets corrupted with proguard.

**Data generated when Json proguard:**

```
{"a":{"a":"Oneil Hooper","b":""},"b":[{"a":"1656952356532","b":0,"q":""} ],"c":["+1986535623355"]}
```

**The data I want to have:**

```
{"displayName":{"name":"Oneil Hooper","surname":""},"b":[{"phoneNumber":"+1656952356532","b":0,"q":"" }],"c":["+1986535623355"]}
```

My jackson proguard:

```
-keep @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties class * { *; }
-keep class com.fasterxml.** { *; }
-keep class org.codehaus.** { *; }
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers public final enum com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect$Visibility {
     public static final com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect$Visibility *;
}

-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper {
     public <methods>;
     protected <methods>;
}

-keep class * implements java.io.Serializable
-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter {
     public ** writeValueAsString(**);
}
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.**
-keep class * implements com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding it like this fixed it: Thank you

```
-keep class * {
        @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator
        <fields>;
        @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty
        <fields>;
        @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator
        <methods>;
        @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty
        <methods>;
    }
    
    -keep class com.fasterxml.** { *; }
    -keep class org.codehaus.** { *; }
    -keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
```